# Number of child running in c++

Tags: c++, linux

I am trying to create, a large number of child processes, say 200, with the following code. I would to print, before moving to the next child, how many childs are still running (out of the ones already created) and how many still to go. Can not to seem to be able to count active running child processes. Any help/hints?

```
int main ()
{
    pid_t pid;
    global_process_count = 0, max_process_count = 200;

    while (global_process_count < max_process_count)
    {
        if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
        {
            perror("fork");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else if (pid == 0)
        {
            // Child process
            exit(EXIT_SUCESS);
        }
        ++global_process_count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why on earth do you want to create 200 processes? BTW go to their funeral as well.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you should also count children exits. A parent process receive a signal (SIGCHLD) everytime a child process terminates (successfully or not). You should set up a signal handler and upon receive a signal gets child's exit code by invoking  `wait()`. See "example 3" [here](http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~pxk/416/notes/c-tutorials/signal.html)

Answer (score 1):

You want the group id of these processes.  A system call will tell you the number of processes in that group.